# Trigonometry - distance and bearing

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> A yacht and a catamaran leave the harbour at $09:00$ hours. The yacht sails at $24$ knots on course $037$ and the catamaran at $15$ knots on $139$. Find the bearing and the distance in nautical miles of the yacht from the catamaran at $1400$ hours ($1$ knot is a speed of $1$ nautical mile per hour).

The final answer I am getting is $135$m using the cosine rule. However this doesn’t match with the solutions. Please could someone clarify both the length and the bearing?

Comment: What do you mean by "courses 037" and "139" ? I suppose it is way to describe orientations but how ?

Comment: I get $154.1668$ miles.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%2875%5E2%2B120%5E2-2*120*75*cos%28102%29%29

Comment: @Saulspatz - yes that is the answer given - how did you do it? Did you also get an answer for the bearing?

Comment: @saulspatz - any diagram would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I used the law of cosines.  Look at the link I posted.  No, I didn't do the bearing.  I'm not exactly sure how navigators take bearings.

Comment: Please use mathjax to show your work. The picture file size was too large.

Comment: @saulspatz - I see. For bearings, drawing a vertical line upwards from a point - that is north. Then going clockwise, the bearing is the angle formed between the vertical and the path you're taking.

Comment: It would be better if you drew the picture.  Where are you having trouble?  What computation did you do?  You should have a triangle with two sides on $75$ and $120$ and an included angle of $102^\circ$.  Is that what your picture shows?

Comment: Why haven't you answered my simple question about course 037? Once I have seen the answers, I have understood it is to be interpreted as 37 degrees taken rightwards from a  vertical direction...  Do you really think that everybody knows this convention ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working using trigonometry.

[image]

$A$ represents position of yacht after $5$ hours. $B$ represents position of Catamaran after $5$ hours.  So,

$OA = 120 $ nautical miles. $OB = 75$ nautical miles.

Angle between $OA$ and $OB = 139^0 - 37^0 = 102^0$.

$AB^2 = 120^2+75^2 + 2 \times 120 \times 75 \cos 102^0 \implies AB \approx 154.167$

$\cos \angle OBA = \frac{75^2 + 154.167^2 - 120^2}{2 \times 75 \times 154.167} \implies \angle OBA \approx 49.58^0$.

So bearing of yatch from catamaran is $49.58^0 - 41^0 \approx 8.58^0$ (which is $8.58^0$ clockwise from true north).

Comment: Thanks @Math Lover - as I say in my comment above: "the given bearing is 115° - does that fit your working if you work back from that?"

Comment: which bearing is given as $115^0$? of the yacht from catamaran?

Comment: @ Math Lover - yes (I am also confused) - but their answer for the distance is correct so it is unlikely they are wrong.

Comment: @ Math Lover - what do you think?

Comment: No that cannot be the bearing from catamaran to yacht or even from yacht to catamaran. $115^0$ is wrong. You can clearly see from the diagram I drew.

Comment: Okay, if you are confident, then that is fine,

Comment: I was confused as well so I think you must be right

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, from 0900 to 1400 that is 5 hours so because 1 knot is 1 nautical mile we can calculate the distance both of the vessels travelled in the time period:

Yacht: 24 * 5 = 120m

Catamaran: 15 * 5 = 75m

From the two bearings at which the vessels set off from the harbour at we can calculate the angle between their paths as:

139 - 37 = 102

Now we can make a triangle with the two distances and the angle between them and the distance between the vessels as the third line.

The cosine rule states: a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc*cos(A)

So to solve the distance between the vessels we substitute in our values to get:

Distance^2 = 120^2 + 75^2 - 2 * 120 * 75 * cos(102) = 23767.41043...

Distance = sqrt(23767.41043...) = 154.1668266...m

You could alternatively do it all in a single step.

Now we have the distance you could use the sine rule to calculate the angle at the catamaran between the yacht and the harbour.

The sine rule for finding angles states: sin(A)/a = sin(B)/b = sin(C)/c

So substituting our values:

sin(angle we want)/120 = sin(102)/154.1668266...

sin(angle we want) = 120 * (sin(102)/154.166266...)

angle we want = sin^-1(120 * (sin(102)/154.166266...)) = 49.58496016...

Now to find the bearing of the yacht from the catamaran we need the angle below the triangle to 270°.

We can do this by finding the remaining angle from the path of the catamaran from the harbour to 180° as 180 - 139 = 41°

Now if you create a right angle triangle below the paths of the boats you can calculate the remaining angle below the angle at the catamaran as 180 - 90 - 41 = 49°

Finally we can calculate the bearing of the yacht from the catamaran as 270 + 49 + 49.58496016... = 368.5849602...°

:/

It seems strange but that is because it goes past north so we can fix this by subtracting 360 leaving the resulting bearing at 008.5849602...°

(don't forget the 000 as you are working in bearings)

In conclusion:

Distance = 154.1668266m

Bearing = 008.5849602°

I cannot guarantee that I am correct but I hope this helps
It is hard to explain without a diagram so it might be useful to sketch one as you follow along. :D

Edit: wow I made a stupid mistake.
I carried forward 41 instead of 49 for the angle below the catamaran!
That puzzled me for a bit.
So carrying on from that you get the correct answer. My bad.

Comment: Thanks @dajaco81 - the given bearing is 115° - does that fit your working if you work back from that?

Comment: so what is your final answer for the bearing?

Comment: I updated it to 008.58

Answer (score 0):

Put the harbor at $(0,0)$ on a Cartesian plane.

Let's measure angles clockwise from the positive $y$ axis, because the $y$ axis is in the "north" direction of a conventional Mercator projection and angles are measured clockwise from north in navigation.

Then after $5$ hours, the coordinates of the yacht are

$$ (120 \sin 37^\circ, 120 \cos 37^\circ) $$

and the coordinates of the catamaran are

$$ (75 \sin 139^\circ, 75\cos 139^\circ). $$

Use the usual formulas to get the distance and direction from the catamaran to the yacht, being careful to measure the angle clockwise from the positive $y$ axis.